# Peculiar 'File not found' pscloudshell error in Azure Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, azure

Well this is strange. I'm running Azure Powershell 5.0.1 in my Azure account and attempting to create an App Service Plan to support [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs); the step

```
az appservice plan create --name myAppServicePlan --resource-group myResourceGroup --sku FREE
```

The error message below references the 'pscloudshell' file (which I've confirmed doesn't exist on my Azure account).

I've tried 
 - verifying that the file exists (it doesn't)
 - a web search on the string 'pscloudshell' and 'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] pscloudshell' (but it's pretty sparse) and

- a search on Stackoverflow on string 'pscloudshell' to find 'Your search returned no matches.'. I must be the first to experience this?!

The error of which I speak is

```
PS Azure:\> az appservice plan create --name myAppServicePlan2 --resource-group myResourceGroup2 --sku FREE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    exit_code = azure.cli.main.main(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\main.py", line 28, in main
    os.makedirs(azure_folder)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\ContainerAdministrator\\CloudDrive\\.pscloudshell'
```

az -v give:

```
azure-cli (2.0.22)

acr (2.0.16)
acs (2.0.21)
advisor (0.1.0)
appservice (0.1.21)
backup (1.0.3)
batch (3.1.7)
batchai (0.1.3)
billing (0.1.6)
cdn (0.0.10)
cloud (2.0.10)
cognitiveservices (0.1.9)
command-modules-nspkg (2.0.1)
configure (2.0.12)
consumption (0.2.0)
container (0.1.14)
core (2.0.22)
cosmosdb (0.1.15)
dla (0.0.15)
dls (0.0.18)
eventgrid (0.1.5)
extension (0.0.6)
feedback (2.0.6)
find (0.2.7)
interactive (0.3.11)
iot (0.1.14)
keyvault (2.0.14)
lab (0.0.13)
monitor (0.0.13)
network (2.0.18)
nspkg (3.0.1)
profile (2.0.15)
rdbms (0.0.9)
redis (0.2.10)
reservations (0.1.0)
resource (2.0.19)
role (2.0.15)
servicefabric (0.0.6)
sql (2.0.16)
storage (2.0.20)
vm (2.0.19)

Python location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe'
Extensions directory 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\CloudDrive\.pscloudshell\.azure\cliextensions'

Python (Windows) 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal
```

Comment: Can you run this command `az -v` in your azure cloud shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run Azure CLI command in PowerShell console of Cloud shell, instead You Should run Azure CLI commands in Bash Shell of cloud shell.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried - verifying that the file exists (it doesn't)

I reproduce your error with an old cloud shell, I can't find `.pscloudshell` in that directory.

Then I delete it from Azure resource group and create a new cloud shell, it works fine:

```
PS C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\CloudDrive> pwd

Path
----
C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\CloudDrive


PS C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\CloudDrive> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\CloudDrive


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       12/13/2017   4:30 AM                .pscloudshell
```

It seems there are some updates with Azure cloud shell, please delete your original cloud shell and **re-create a new one**.